# Cordova getting transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug build error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build.gradle

I copied my whole project into a new directory and then in the new directory updated the platform and all the SDKs (via Android Studio), I also added support for Android v4 and now I am getting build errors (mostly related to v4). The original build directory is still working fine. I won't mess with the original until I know the copied app is building cleanly.

In the copied/updated project, I added the latest Android platform:

copiedApp:> cordova platform add android@latest

/myOrigApp - // Android 5.1.1, works fine after all SDKs updated.

/myCopiedApp - // Android 5.2.1, getting the below errors.

I 'think' I fixed the first build error: Error 1:
`Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$Acces
sibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;`

by adding to the platform\adroid\build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

but am now getting Error 2.

```
`Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/TimeUtils.class`
```

Still researching this one, but thinking it has to do with extra v4 build files or need to delete the v4 folders because gradle is installing them even though not defined in the gradle (that I can see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Extract from our [exchange in a Github issue](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy/issues/11)**

This is almost certainly being caused by multiple instances of the Android v4 support library being included.

Looking at the plugins you have installed, `phonegap-facebook-plugin 0.12.0 "Facebook Connect"` [includes it as a JAR](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/v0.12.0/platforms/android/FacebookLib/libs).

The Facebook plugin really needs to be updated to use Gradle as the use of this JAR file will cause collisions with any other plugins making use of the Android v4 support library - it seems other people are experiencing similar issues [see here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1263).

Try this ([see here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1183)):

Edit `plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookConnect/plugin.xml` and replace the line:

```
<framework src="platforms/android/FacebookLib" custom="true" />
```

with

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:+" />
<framework src="com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0" />
```

Remove and re-add the platform:

```
cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android@latest
```

Personally, I would choose the last option, but I'd also consider forking the Facebook plugin Github repo and apply these changes to my fork, then installing my forked plugin to my local project to avoid losing these local changes if your `/plugins` folder is removed for some reason:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/your_account/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --save
```